# how to delete every nth range of rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, sequence

Suppose I have a dataframe df, which contains 450 rows. I want to delete rows from 10 through 18 (that is 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18). Then similarly rows from 28 through 36, then 46:54. And so on, up to deleting rows from 442 through 450.

Any suggestions, guys?

Comment: Can you please show anything you've already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `sequence` and remove those rows. The first argument, `nvec`, is the length of each sequence (8, repeated for each sequence); the second, `from`, is the starting point for each sequence (10, 28, ...).

```r
n = 450
len = n %/% 18
s <- sequence(nvec = rep(9, len), from = seq(10, n, 18))
# [1]  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  28  29  30  31  32  33  34
# [17]  35  36  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  64  65  66  67  68
# [33]  69  70  71  72  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90 100 101 102
# ...

your_df[-s, ]
```

You can also create the sequence like this:

```r
rep(10:18, len) + rep(18*(0:(len - 1)), each = 9)
# [1]  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  28  29  30  31  32  33  34
# [17]  35  36  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  64  65  66  67  68
# [33]  69  70  71  72  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90 100 101 102
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! The only weird part is that 'sequence' does not remove the last 9 rows,  442-450

Comment: see edit. Just add 1 to len

Comment: sorry dude, I didn't get your last point. Where have you added 1 to len –? I tried both ways of "sequence", but the result is the same, it does not remove the last 9 rows, 442-450.

Comment: I changed the `len` object. It was 24 before edit, 25 now. `s` does include 442-450